# Random Containers when adding link to collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've added a right side list group to my site using bootstrap and then I added a collapse to every list group item, all these worked successfully. I am able to add text to the list group collapse without anything bad happening. However, whenever I try to add links, the collapse just leaves the link outside of the container box where the text is enclosed in.

Here is the code to one list-group element:

```
 <!-- Defines the collpase method !-->
 <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" href="#mapscollapse">
 <!-- Glypicon added !-->
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right vcenter"></span>
 <!--Added heading as maps !-->
 <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Maps</h4>
 <!--Collpase Target !-->
 <div id="mapscollapse" class="collapse">
 <!-- Links !-->
 <ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.google.com" id = "link">Google</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

The link to the site: http://www.tabletstudios.ca/csgo.html click on maps section to see the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an not use `<a>` tag inside `<a>` that's the reason it's going out of the container. To fix this for container you need to use `<div>` tag instead of `<a>`

your structure is

```
<div id="homecollapse" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style=""><a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" href="#homecollapse" aria-expanded="true">
                          </a><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="link">Visit W3Schools</a>
                        </div>
```

update your structure as follows

```
<div id="homecollapse" class="collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style=""><div class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" href="#homecollapse" aria-expanded="true">
      <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="link">Visit W3Schools</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do this? Or be a little more specific? Thanks for reply

Comment: Updated sample code in answer try it I hope it will solve your problem Thanks